# How to use secrets mounted on AKS

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-keyvault, azure-aks, kubernetes-secrets

I followed this setup guide on how to [Integrate Azure Key Vault with Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-integrate-kubernetes).

The setup was successful, my problem now is how to use those secrets that are mounted in AKS?

The following code in my .net application doesn't seem to work. It doesn't get the secrets and it's returning an exception.

`Configuration["ConnectionString"]`

I do see the ConnectionString when running `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> ls /mnt/secrets` and can also view the content.

Comment: What code did you add to your application that lets it read that file?

Comment: @DaImTo, which file are you referring to?

Comment: The ones stored in /mnt/secret-store.  Each secret has a file in that directory im having issues on how to get Configuration to load them.

Answer (score 0):

After almost 1 week of figuring this issue out, at last, it's working now. The error was caused by not supplying the clientId and clientSecret because I forgot to add it when I pushed my changes.

Using `Configuration["ConnectionString"]` should work, it will get the key vault secret that's mounted in kubernetes.